# Can I use both "soft" and "intr" options for mounting a NFS CIFS drive? If yes, in which order?

Tags: mount, cifs

I have faced a problem recently with a NFS mapping. An I/O process (`cp`) got in **uninterruptible sleep state** and I ended up having to reboot the machine to fix the problem. Rebooting was bad so I don't want this to happen again.

It was mounted as follows:

```
mount //path/to/network/drive /path/to/folder -o domain=DOMAIN_HERE,username=USERNAME_HERE
```

It was a CIFS mount because the `//path/to/network/drive` is a windows filesystem (but I assume the command above figured this out automatically, since I didn't specify CIFS explicitly).

Upon investigating I found out that it was a "hard-mount" and that was a part of the problem. I found that a "soft-mount" could have helped, and also the `intr` option could have helped too.

So now I want to mount it again, but instead of simply calling the above command, I was thinking of calling it as follows:

```
mount //path/to/network/drive /path/to/folder -o soft,intr,domain=DOMAIN_HERE,username=USERNAME_HERE
```

Does this work? Are `soft` and `intr` compatible? I don't understand deeply what they do exactly but I've seen that they should help prevent the same issue from happening again because nothing would ever reach the **uninterruptible sleep state** with them. Also, since apparently [option order matters](https://askubuntu.com/a/190710/538283), is the ordering above ok?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, NFS is a file share protocol of its own that is not CIFS / SMB. Yes, it is a very generic name, but because NFS inspired some of these mount options and other conventions, be very clear in what you are using.

---

`intr` doesn't do anything.

[CIFS:](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man8/mount.cifs.8.html)

> **intr**   currently unimplemented.

[NFS:](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man5/nfs.5.html)

> **intr / nointr**  This  option  is  provided for backward
>   compatibility.  It is ignored after
>                         kernel 2.6.25.

`soft` is the mount option to use if you value fast failure. `hard` values data integrity and will hang the client if the server goes away.

---

You cannot escape the possibility of the file server going away unexpectedly leaving uninterruptable processes around. At best you minimize the risk by making the file share as reliable as you can, and reducing the use of such mounts on your system.

---

I assumed Linux. Please state your operating system going forward because various UNIXes and even the Linux distros may be different.